# Fill zero values for combinations of unique multi-index values after groupby

Tags: python, pandas

To better explain by problem better lets pretend i have a shop with 3 unique customers and my dataframe contains every purchase of my customers with weekday, name and paid price.

```
     name  price  weekday
0    Paul  18.44        0
1   Micky   0.70        0
2   Sarah   0.59        0
3   Sarah   0.27        1
4    Paul   3.45        2
5   Sarah  14.03        2
6    Paul  17.21        3
7   Micky   5.35        3
8   Sarah   0.49        4
9   Micky  17.00        4
10   Paul   2.62        4
11  Micky  17.61        5
12  Micky  10.63        6
```

The information i would like to get is the average price per unique customer per weekday. What i often do in similar situations is to group by several columns with sum and then take the average of a subset of the columns.

```
df = df.groupby(['name','weekday']).sum()



              price
name  weekday       
Micky 0         0.70
      3         5.35
      4        17.00
      5        17.61
      6        10.63
Paul  0        18.44
      2         3.45
      3        17.21
      4         2.62
Sarah 0         0.59
      1         0.27
      2        14.03
      4         0.49

df = df.groupby(['weekday']).mean()

             price
weekday           
0         6.576667
1         0.270000
2         8.740000
3        11.280000
4         6.703333
5        17.610000
6        10.630000
```

Of course this only works if all my unique customers would have at least one purchase per day. 
Is there an elegant way to get a zero value for all combinations between unique index values that have no sum after the first groupby?

My solutions has been so far to either to reindex on a multi index i created from the unique values of the grouped columns or the combination of unstack-fillna-stack but both solutions do not really satisfy me.

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, let's use `unstack` and `fillna` then `stack`:

```
df_out = df.groupby(['name','weekday']).sum().unstack().fillna(0).stack()
```

Output:

```
               price
name  weekday       
Micky 0         0.70
      1         0.00
      2         0.00
      3         5.35
      4        17.00
      5        17.61
      6        10.63
Paul  0        18.44
      1         0.00
      2         3.45
      3        17.21
      4         2.62
      5         0.00
      6         0.00
Sarah 0         0.59
      1         0.27
      2        14.03
      3         0.00
      4         0.49
      5         0.00
      6         0.00
```

And,

```
df_out.groupby('weekday').mean()
```

Output:

```
            price
weekday          
0        6.576667
1        0.090000
2        5.826667
3        7.520000
4        6.703333
5        5.870000
6        3.543333
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `pivot_table` to do all the steps at once. I'm not exactly sure what you want but the default aggregation from `pivot_table` is the mean. You can change it to 'sum'.

```
df1 = df.pivot_table(index='name', columns='weekday', values='price', 
                     fill_value=0, aggfunc='sum')

weekday      0     1      2      3      4      5      6
name                                                   
Micky     0.70  0.00   0.00   5.35  17.00  17.61  10.63
Paul     18.44  0.00   3.45  17.21   2.62   0.00   0.00
Sarah     0.59  0.27  14.03   0.00   0.49   0.00   0.00
```

And then take the mean of each column.

```
df1.mean()

weekday
0    6.576667
1    0.090000
2    5.826667
3    7.520000
4    6.703333
5    5.870000
6    3.543333
```